# Is it safe to allow links that start with # (hash)?

Tags: security, url, xss, google-caja

I'm building a webapp and users can create HTML contents dynamically. Is it safe (e.g. w.r.t. XSS attacks) to allow them to create links that start with `#`?

I don't know why it wouldn't be -- perhaps I'm just being paranoid.
(My Javascript code doesn't do anything particular, for `#` URLs.)

Anyway one reason I ask is that I'm using [Google Caja's html-sanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer) to sanitize HTML. It filters URL:s, *however* the default filter looks like so:

```
function urlX(url) { if(/^https?:\/\//.test(url)) { return url }}
```

That is, the protocol must be specified and only HTTP and HTTPS are allowed but not `javascript:`. I recently changed the URL filtering function to:

```
function urlX(url) {
  if (/^https?:\/\//.test(url) || /^#/.test(url)) return url;
}
```

(That is, `#....` is allowed as well.)

I thought that perhaps I should ask if you think `#...` links are safe?

(For example, the browser won't do anything insane with links like  `href='#javascript:....'? Well it does not (not my browser anyway), but perhaps there is some other ...something... that I'm not aware about)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *should* be safe: anything after a `#` in a URL is parsed as a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) by browsers.

Of course, if you have some JavaScript on the page that reads that fragment identifier and does something unsafe with it, then all bets are off.  But note that, in such a case, you have a more fundamental security problem that you need to fix.

Just disallowing links than begin with `#` won't do much, since an attacker could still include a malicious fragment identifier in a full URL, or even in a link pointing to your site from somewhere else.

Comment: "*an attacker could still include a malicious fragment identifier in a full URL*" -- that's a good point

Answer (score 3):

It's not safe. For example, there was an XSS issue with jQuery's `$(location.hash)`. There is PoC at http://ma.la/jquery_xss/.

So either forbid this or properly sanitize everything after #

Comment: Of course, an XSS vulnerability like that would be pretty easy to exploit even if you _don't_ allow links beginning with `#` in user content.  If you're vulnerable to that attack, you should really fix the actual vulnerability.  (There's a general security principle involved here: never pass unfiltered user input to [DWIM](http://catb.org/jargon/html/D/DWIM.html) functions like jQuery's `$(...)` or PHP's `fopen()`, etc.)

Comment: Interesting! (And I agree with @IlmariKaronen that the "correct" solution is to upgrade/patch jQuery)

Comment: I just realized that your regex is wrong because I can post `http://yoursite.com#evil` and it will pass. So, anchors are anyway in game.